# Dynamic Link Library using makefile

Tags: c, dynamic, makefile, shared-libraries, gnu-make

Hello to the good people of Stack Overflow, I am back at it again with the questions! haha
So I have a couple of files that I am trying to compile and link together. The library I have created is a DLL. Using a `RTLD_LAZY` method. I have the library in the same directory as the application. I'm having a tough time completing this task. I'm trying to link it using `-ldl`.

My files that I have are:

```
lab3.c        //Which has my main
myLibrary.c   //which is my library
sdv.h         //which is my header file 
testDynamic.c //which is my handle file for the RTLD_LAZY
```

Here is what I have done so far, but I'm clearly screwing something up..

```
dynamic: lab3.o myLibrary.o test
        gcc -o dynamic lab3.o myLibrary.o -lm

lab3.o: lab3.c
        gcc -fPIC -c -o lab3.o lab3.c -lm

myLibrary.o: myLibrary.c
        gcc -fPIC -c myLibrary.c -o myLibrary.o -lm 

libmyLibrary.so: myLibrary.o
        gcc -shared -o libmyLibrary.so myLibrary.o -lm

testDynamic.o:
        gcc testDynamic.c -L. -lmyLibrary -o test -ldl

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give the error message and minimal source for testDynamic ?

Comment: "The library I have created is a DLL" "libmyLibrary.so", this seems to me a bit confusing, a DLL gives me the impression you use for windows, but .so file are dynamic libraries for UNIX, so what is your OS exactly?

Comment: The error I am getting is "error while loading shared libraries: libmyLibrary.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory @dvhh

Comment: @dvhh And for my handle details .....int main(){

void *handle;
char *err;

void(*sphere_d)(float, float *, float *);
float(*volCylinder_d)(float, float);
float(*sumFloats_d)(float [], int);
double(*sine_d)(float);

handle = dlopen("libmyLibrary.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if(handle == (void *)0){
        fputs(dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(-1);

 }

sphere_d = dlsym(handle, "sphere");
err = dlerror();
        if(err != NULL){
        fputs(err, stderr);
        exit(-1);
}

volCylinder_d = dlsym(handle, "volCylinder");
err = dlerror();
        if( err != NULL){

Comment: I am using fedora! Sorry I thought DLL was a common abbreviation for dynamic link library. It is a .so file. @jdarthenay

Comment: Ok so... launching my Debian virtual machine to try your makefile...

Comment: Are you really using this makefile? why the last target is named testDynamic.o and not test? I searched what means RTLD_LAZY, it seems to mean you load library manually with dynamic methods, so why do you add -lmyLibrary when building test?

Comment: Well that's kinda what I was hoping you could clear up. I'm confused on making this make file. The reason I didn't you testdynamic.o is because testdynamic isn't necessarily an object file. @jdarthenay

Comment: Ok, in this case please do the following: edit your question, add at the end "Edit: this is my code" and put each of your source and header files with its content because the code in your comment is unreadable and got truncated (comments are not supposed to contain code of full files).

Answer (score 2):

Here comes an example close to your own makefile.

makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99

.PHONY:all mrproper clean


all:libmyLibrary.so dynamic testDynamic 

dynamic:lab3.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o dynamic lab3.o -L. -lmyLibrary -lm

lab3.o:lab3.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o lab3.o lab3.c

myLibrary.o:myLibrary.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c myLibrary.c -o myLibrary.o

libmyLibrary.so:myLibrary.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -o libmyLibrary.so myLibrary.o -lm

testDynamic.o:testDynamic.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o testDynamic.o -c testDynamic.c

testDynamic:testDynamic.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o testDynamic testDynamic.o -ldl

mrproper:clean
    rm -f dynamic libmyLibrary.so testDynamic

clean:
    rm -f lab3.o myLibrary.o testDynamic.o
```

Use `-lm` only when linking. `-fPic` is only necessary when linking dynamic library. `-lmyLibrary` is only necessary when linking program with dynamic library. So generating `testDynamic` does not need it as it will load library dynamically, it does not require being linked to it.

sdv.h:

```
#ifndef SDV_H
#define SDV_H

extern void sdv_print_version();

#endif
```

myLibrary.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sdv_print_version()
{
    printf("v1.0\n");
}
```

testDynamic.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <dlfcn.h>

#define MY_LIB "libmyLibrary.so"
#define PRINT_VERSION "sdv_print_version"

int main()
{
    void *handle = dlopen(MY_LIB, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }

    void (*p_print_version)() = NULL;
    p_print_version = dlsym(handle, PRINT_VERSION);
    if (p_print_version == NULL)
    {
        printf("No version available.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    }
    else
    {
        (*p_print_version)();
    }

    if (dlclose(handle) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now building:

```
>make
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -fPIC -c myLibrary.c -o myLibrary.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -shared -o libmyLibrary.so myLibrary.o -lm
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -c -o lab3.o lab3.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -o dynamic lab3.o -L. -lmyLibrary -lm
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -o testDynamic.o -c testDynamic.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -o testDynamic testDynamic.o -ldl
```

Let's keep a first version of dynamic library:

```
>mkdir v1.0
>mv libmylibrary.so v1.0/
```

Now update myLibrary.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sdv_print_version()
{
    printf("v2.0\n");
}
```

Build again:

```
>make
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -fPIC -c myLibrary.c -o myLibrary.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -shared -o libmyLibrary.so myLibrary.o -lm
```

Let's move this new dynamic library to another directory:

```
>mkdir v2.0
>mv libmylibrary.so v2.0/
```

Now testing with no dynamic library available:

```
>export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./
>PATH=$PATH:.
>dynamic
dynamic: error while loading shared libraries: libmyLibrary.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>testDynamic
libmyLibrary.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What's the difference? In "testDynamic.c" we could, instead of showing a message error, do an alternative algorithm not requiring "libmyLibrary.so".

Now checking we can use "libmyLibrary.so":

```
>cd v1.0
>../dynamic
v1.0
>../testDynamic
v1.0
>cd ../v2.0
>../dynamic
v2.0
>../testDynamic
v2.0
```